# Xcode 4: Outlet not staying connected at runtime

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xcode4, outlet

I have a UIViewController with a UITableView on it. I've set the tableview's `dataSource` and `delegate` to File's Owner, and also created a referencing outlet to a property called `resultsTable` (that is connected to `_resultsTable` via `@synthesize resultsTable=_resultsTable`). Everything is connected properly in IB. I've triple checked this.

When I run the app, the table wasn't getting updated properly. So I added this line into `viewDidLoad`, to see what's going on:

```
    NSLog(@"resultsTable: %@ | delegate: %@ | datasource: %@", _resultsTable, _resultsTable.delegate, _resultsTable.dataSource);
```

I get (null) for each value.

I'm totally stumped. I've done this a hundred times and I've never had this problem, so I'm starting to question my sanity again.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I've gone ahead and created the UITableView programatically and it works fine, but I'd still love to know why this wasn't working. Strange.

Comment: Was your View Controller a UITableViewController or a UIViewController? Is it possible you had the latter and forgot to extend UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate? Alternately, perhaps you were initializing your view controller with the wrong init method?